# Group cohomology of $\mathbb{Z}$ vs $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, cohomology, group-cohomology, modules

Let $M$ be a continuous representation of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$, likely infinite-dimensional.

There is the inflation map of group cohomology $H^*_{\text{cts}}(\mathbb{Z}_p, M) \rightarrow H^*(\mathbb{Z}, M)$. It would of course be an isomorphism if $M$ were finite-dimensional. Are there natural conditions that guarantee it is an isomorphism in general?

Comment: Is this map inflation or restriction?

Comment: Given $A \rightarrow B$, I call "inflation" the procedure of regarding a $B$-module as an $A$-module via this map. Maybe other people call it "restriction" but I think there is only one possible map in the given situation.

Comment: Maybe such a condition would be that the module is smooth, namely that every point of $M$ is stabilized by an open subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. In general the map is not surjective on $H^1$.